# nil users after creating 100 of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial (9.2)

http://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#cha-updating_showing_and_deleting_users

and I am getting this error.

I am getting this error here

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

<h1>All users</h1>

  <ul class="users">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li>
        <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
```

I created 100 users using `gem 'faker', '1.1.2'`. I am not sure why there are `nil` users when I've just created 100 of them.

I also ran these commands

```
bundle exec rake db:reset
bundle exec rake db:populate
bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

Comment: and did you set your `@users` variable in the controller's action corresponding to the view you're accessing? If yes, show us how you did it ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is NOT that you don't have any users.  If you had no users, `@users` would be an empty array and the `.each` method would work happily (although there would be nothing to iterate over)

So the problem is that `@users` is not being initialized correctly.

Look at listing 9.23 on the page you referenced.  Do you have this code in your controller?

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

That's likely what's missing.

Comment: There was a typo. It was set to `@user` instead of `@users`. Thank you!